# Sending data through views in swift xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to send data though the view controllers.

If I click on a cell, I have a segue that transfers me to another view controller. I have a label on that that I want to change according to what the text in the cell clicked was.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
import UIKit
```

class FirstViewController: UIViewController{

var storedString = String()

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var venue : VenueItems

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        venue = self.filteredVenues[indexPath.row]
        var name = venue.name
        storedStadiumSelected = name
    }
    else
    {
        venue = self.venuesArray[indexPath.row]
        var name = venue.name
        storedStadiumSelected = name
    }


    println(storedStadiumSelected)

}
```

code inbetween here...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var nextViewController: SelectBookingTypeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SelectBookingTypeViewController

    nextViewController.recievedStadiumSelected = storedStadiumSelected

}
```

my second view controller looks like this:
import UIKit

class SelectBookingTypeViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var stadiumLabel: UILabel!

var recievedStadiumSelected = String()


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    stadiumLabel.text = recievedStadiumSelected
}
```

The problem with this code is that I am only loading the option I clicked before. So for example, if I click 'item1', the label text is nothing.
But if I go back and click 'item2', the label is now item1. I don't know why this happens!

I am relatively new to coding so excuse me,
Thank you, any help would be taken with enthusiasm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place to look is in the Xcode template for `Master-Detail Application` that Apple Provides. Here is the code on the DetailViewController you looking for. The

DetailViewController

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!


var detailItem: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view.
        self.configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
            label.text = detail.description

        }
    }
}
```

MasterViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
```

TableView code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! NSDate

    //This Code here tells the label to update for the cell selected.
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.description 

    return cell
}
```

So you will need this in you're secondViewController

```
func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem {
        if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {

            //Change the label name to match yours.
            yourLabelName.text = detail.description
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can kind of understand this code, please can you change and edit the code that it suits mine more please? @Jason

Comment: I guess I should have you clarify, the label.text you're trying to change based on the cell selected. What are you wanting the label text to be? The same as the cell?

Comment: If you're wanting the label text the same as the cell selected, then you don't need to store the value like you're trying to do, just set it. `cell.textLabel!.text = object.description`

Comment: Is there a download link for the Master-Detail Application ? @Jason

Comment: In xcode, start new project, select the Master-Detail Application.